# Try catch for RSelenium errors

Tags: r, rselenium

I use RSelenium to check some pages.

I visit this pages using a for loop.

However sometimes I receive this error:

```
Selenium message:stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.167)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)

Error:   Summary: StaleElementReference
     Detail: An element command failed because the referenced element is no longer attached to the DOM.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

and my program stops.

Because I have never used try catch in RSelenium how can I write to add a try catch in the for loop?

I found this from a python example:

```
for x in range(0, len(df.index)):
       try:
           twitter(df.username[x])
           print x
       except TweepError:
           pass
```

The know that `TweepError` and just pass the error and go to next iteration.

I have a same for loop in r:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  url <- df$page[i]
  testpage(url)
}
```

How could it be possible to make something like python ir r?

I tried something like this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  url <- df$page[i]
  try(testpage(url))
}
```

but I receive the error :

```
Error in testpage(url) : could not find function "testpage"
```

I have runned the function before the for and I can see it in enviroment variables and the name is right.

Comment: Please include the code you are running that gives this error.

Comment: @C.Braun The code is a little big to provide it but could it be possible to include an example in which a function without input make something like this in python `try:
           twitter()
       except TweepError:
           pass`

Comment: @C.Braun I have updated my question. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest equivalent of python's `try` is `tryCatch`:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  url <- df$page[i]
  tryCatch({
    testpage(url)
  }, error = function( err ) {
    print(paste( "Error:", err ))
    # You can run more code here
    # ...
  })
}
```